# HttpClient 302 redirect

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, http-status-code-302

I have 2 urls: `https://pcr.apple.com/id868222886` and `https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/302.html`. Both have a location link and 302 response code.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace XaveScor.PodcastFeed
{
    public class RemoteFeedSource: FeedSource
    {
        private string url;
        protected virtual HttpMessageHandler Handler => new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = true };

        public override Stream Stream => client.Value.GetStreamAsync(url).Result;

        private readonly Lazy<HttpClient> client;

        public RemoteFeedSource(string url)
        {
            client = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => new HttpClient(Handler), false);    
            this.url = url;
        }
    }
}


[TestMethod]
public void Test1() //fail
{
    var source = new RemoteFeedSource("https://pcr.apple.com/id868222886");
    Assert.AreNotEqual(source.Stream.GetString(), "");
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test2() //success
{
    var source = new RemoteFeedSource("https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/302.html");
    Assert.AreNotEqual(source.Stream.GetString(), "");
}
```

Why? What is difference?

Comment: The difference, in what sense? 302 = Found (and is often used for redirects), 301 = Moved permanently. See [here](https://developer.att.com/application-resource-optimizer/docs/best-practices/http-300-status-codes).

Comment: @john I have two identical, I think, links. But HttpClient work is different on this links. My question is why. Why the behavior is different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the headers in the response, you'll see this:

First one (https://pcr.apple.com/id868222886):

```
Content-Length: 0
Location: http://beardycast.libsyn.com/rss
```

Second one (https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/302.html):

```
Content-Length: 389
Content-Type:   text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Location:       https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/Overview.html
```

So the first server silently redirects you, and the second one provides some additional headers for you:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552015; includeSubDomains; preload
Public-Key-Pins: pin-sha256="cN0QSpPIkuwpT6iP2YjEo1bEwGpH/yiUn6yhdy+HNto="; pin-sha256="WGJkyYjx1QMdMe0UqlyOKXtydPDVrk7sl2fV+nNm1r4="; pin-sha256="LrKdTxZLRTvyHM4/atX2nquX9BeHRZMCxg3cf4rhc2I="; max-age=864000
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

And the response body:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
               "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <title>Moved</title>
</head>
<body>
<P>This resources has moved, click on the link if your browser doesn't support automatic redirection<BR>
<A HREF="http://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/Overview.html">http://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/Overview.html</A></body>
</html>
```

This is why `HttpClient` returns non-empty result string - it's not really empty. Your unit tests have wrong design approach, as they do not check the status, but do check only response length, which could be non-empty even for `3**` http status codes.